# Breaking down the scene into squares

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, javafx

How do I break down a 400x400 scene into 40 equal pairs (10x10 squares)?

Is the best approach to use a two-dimensional array? How do I select each square after I've divided the screen into 40 equal 10x10 squares?

Source code examples and/or tutorials will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm using JavaFX

Thanks.

```
    final Group root = new Group();

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: So far what have do done?

Comment: Not much. Still trying to figure out  how to go about breaking the scene down into pieces.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux a scene is JavaFX's mid-level container (stage being the top level). A stage is basically the displayed window.

Comment: What do you want do display in those squares? I would suggest taking a look at the JavaFX GridPane

Comment: Code optimization is my goal. so I can locate what's inside each square and only process data there.

Comment: What are you going to do with these squares? Is it chess like game? Is it grid ruler of the scene? My suggestion is to put some selectable and stylable controls (rectangle, label or even button) into flowpane.

Comment: @UlukBiy check this out for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495864/uniform-grid-collision-detection-between-circles-in-2d

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're going to be doing with those 40 squares.  GridPane is one way to go, however, if you're needing to divide it up for something else though (for example if you were making a chess board) you could create individual Square objects where each section would be.  Then you can set them to a color, set actions on touch/click/etc, set what square's chess piece you want to select and what square you want to move it to, you could also set a picture to each one, etc.  Also, if you need it that way, you can make the squares transparent so they can't be seen but actions will still happen when the user does something that effects that particular square.  It wouldn't be too difficult to write a method that creates a new square in each section for you either instead of you hard coding them in yourself- it could be done recursively too, for efficiency purposes, if you don't mind losing a little memory.